# SQLite 3 statement preparation segfault

Tags: c, sqlite, segmentation-fault

I'm using SQLite 3 in a C application of mine. It has worked like a charm up until now, when I've started to write unit tests. The function in question is a pretty small. It opens an in-memory database, prepares a statement and then does some stuff with it. Problem is that the app crashes with a segmentation fault at the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function call. I've tried to debug it and check to see that all arguments are valid, which they seem to be.

Below, I've pasted a minimal example which causes segfault in the same way. The backtrace lists `sqlite3LockAndPrepare` as the function where it crashes (called by `sqlite3_prepare_v2`).

As I mentioned above, I use SQLite without any problems in the rest of my app. I just can't figure out what the difference in usage is, since it's split up in several different routines which also does other stuff. The one thing I can spot is the use of an in-memory database instead of on-disk, but I tried with it on disk, and it made no difference.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt **stmt;
    const char *str = "CREATE TABLE Test (t1 varchar(8) NOT NULL);";

    if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db)) {
        printf("Can't open...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, str, -1, stmt, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: never used sqlite from c, but isn't `db` already a pointer to an sqlite instance, and then you're passing in the address of the pointer, not the pointer itself to the open() call?

Comment: It's supposed to be a `sqlite3 **` https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: @fridge, You are correct that the second argument to `sqlite3_open()` is supposed to be an `sqlite3 **`.  And that's what it is in the sample code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah I was answering Marc B, just forgot to mention him.

Comment: @fridge, got it, sorry.  So yes, Marc B, an `sqlite **` is what's expected.  That's how the function provides an `sqlite *` back to its caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth argument to `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` is supposed to be a valid pointer to an `sqlite3_stmt *`.  You are instead passing an undefined value (since your variable `stmt` is never initialized).  (Note, too, that even if that did not crash the program, you could not receive a pointer to the prepared statement that way.)

You should do this, instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    const char *str = "CREATE TABLE Test (t1 varchar(8) NOT NULL);";

    /* ... create database ... */    

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, str, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```